# Count every Button clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net

The task is to count the number of clicks in a webform.

Here is the code.

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int count = 1;
        private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Click Me";
            btn.Click  += btn_Click;
            Label lbl = new Label();
            form1.Controls.Add(btn);
            form1.Controls.Add(lbl);


        }

        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            //Label1.Text = count.ToString();

        }
    }
```

The problem is that **lbl** is not recognised inside **btn_Click()** ... I can't figure it out... can anyone suggest?

Comment: If the task is to count "every" click probably you may want to consider creating a user control !

Comment: ok i think i have figured it out a bit... every time i am pressing the button i am getting a new page load and hence the value is again initialised to the initial value which is one in my case... So i need to store the value in some place where irrespective of the page load's my the value is not changed ... viewstate is good i think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare lbl outside the page_load method than it will be available to you in button click like this.

```
Label lbl ;
int count = 1;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = "Click Me";
    btn.Click  += btn_Click;
    lbl = new Label();
    form1.Controls.Add(btn);
    form1.Controls.Add(lbl);
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    if(lbl !=null)
      lbl.Text = count.ToString();            
}
```

Because if you create label in the page_load scope of the variable is limited to that method only. So either you declare the label outside the method like as I did or you can give id to label and than search it using `FindControl` method.

Comment: is it applicable for all other controls also ??

Comment: and more to that ... the counter is not incremnting after 2... logic is wrong it think. but where is the problem ???

Comment: @Tony for the increment of `count` to work it has to be `static` I think

Answer (score 2):

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Label id="lbl" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Code-Behind (C#):

```
int count = 1;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lbl.Text = count.ToString();
    }
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(lbl.Text, out count))
    {                
        lbl.Text = (++count).ToString();
    }
}
```